# How should VS Code extensions modify user config?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried to use `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(...).update(...)`.

But it only takes effect in the current workspace, and will create `.vscode/settings.json` if it does not exist.

I need to modify the user's global config. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` method accepts a `configurationTarget` parameter, which defines *where* the configuration will be applied.

```js
   /**
   * Update a configuration value. The updated configuration values are persisted.
   *
   * A value can be changed in
   *
   * - {@link ConfigurationTarget.Global Global settings}: Changes the value for all instances of the editor.
   * - {@link ConfigurationTarget.Workspace Workspace settings}: Changes the value for current workspace, if available.
   * - {@link ConfigurationTarget.WorkspaceFolder Workspace folder settings}: Changes the value for settings from one of the {@link workspace.workspaceFolders Workspace Folders} under which the requested resource belongs to.
   * - Language settings: Changes the value for the requested languageId.
   *
   ...
   */
   update(section: string, value: any, configurationTarget?: ConfigurationTarget | boolean | null, overrideInLanguage?: boolean): Thenable<void>;
```

Where `ConfigurationTarget` can be:

```js
/**
     * The configuration target
     */
    export enum ConfigurationTarget {
        /**
         * Global configuration
        */
        Global = 1,

        /**
         * Workspace configuration
         */
        Workspace = 2,

        /**
         * Workspace folder configuration
         */
        WorkspaceFolder = 3
    }
```

So, you should do something like:

```js
   vscode.workspace.getConfiguration(...).update(someSection, someValue, ConfigurationTarget.Global,...)
```

Hope this helps